# from address in mail in liferay

Tags: java, liferay, jakarta-mail, liferay-6

I am working with liferay 6.0.6. I am using gmail smtp server to send emails from liferay .In my mail configuration while configuring gmail smtp mail serverI used my gmail id(krishna@gmail.com) . My method has following code .

```java
InternetAddress fromAddress = new InternetAddress("admin@krishnaorg.com");
InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(emailIdsArray);
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage( fromAddress,toAddress , subject ,mailBody , true);
MailServiceUtil.sendEmail(mailMessage);
```

When i send a mail. The mail have from address "krishna@gmail.com", but I want from address to be " admin@krishnaorg.com ".  How can I achieve this??

Comment: mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("test@liferay.com","your name"));  try this

Answer (score 3):

This is a full example:

```
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.mail.MailMessage
import com.liferay.mail.service.MailServiceUtil

sender = new InternetAddress()
sender.setAddress("sender@notifier.it")
sender.setPersonal("Sender name")

receiver = new InternetAddress()
receiver.setAddress("cuuvwksw@sharklasers.com")

subject = "mail subject"
body = "body"

message = new MailMessage()

message.setFrom(sender)
message.setTo(receiver)
message.setSubject(subject)
message.setBody(body)
message.setHTMLFormat(false)

MailServiceUtil.sendEmail(message)
```

Comment: MailServiceUtil.sendEmail is an non-blocking operation: the actual sending will happen in a background thread. If you want to send a msg synchronously, use MailEngine.send.

Answer (score 0):

try this

mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("test@liferay.com","your name"));

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this .

Use following code and try it may work

```
com.liferay.util.mail.MailEngine.send(InternetAddress from, InternetAddress to, String subject,String body, boolean htmlFormat);
```

if its bulk mail sending then use following method

```
com.liferay.util.mail.MailEngine.send(InternetAddress from, InternetAddress[] to, InternetAddress[] cc,String subject, String body, boolean htmlFormat);
```

InternetAddress[] cc for you can pass null if you don't have cc addresses